# How can i access my custom webpart in sharepoint foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So i just started trying to develop a simple webpart today for a sharepoint foundation i put on a virtual machine. I have no previous experience with sharepoint whatsoever.

As i cant run a sharepoint 2010 on my local machine for dev purposes i followed advices in this thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/cda807f6-4edf-4efc-8e9b-4d446356c8ae to able to actually develop something (just the registry bit).

I created the simple test web part (writes out "hi"), uploaded it to virtual machine, added it with add-spsolution and install-spsolution in powershell with success. When i do get-solution through powershell on my webpart it says deployed  = true.

What am i missing from here to get it to actually show up somewhere in the web interface so i can add it to a page?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into site settings and activate the feature. If its already activated edit the page > Insert WebPart > Look under Custom to find your webpart.

HTH

Comment: Ok, on my top most site i went under site settings > galleries > webparts - and it is not listed here. Is it supposed to be when it is deployed?

Comment: Oh and there is at the moment no custom folder in the categories section of the insert web part stage when im editing my page. This is really what prompted me to ask.

Comment: Ok - i activated/enabled the feature through powershell, and now it appears. I guess there are alot of sharepoint basics im clueless to. With that said, why on earth is it so ridiculously difficult to develop a web part locally and deploy to a remote machine?

Comment: Your lucky you are starting with sp2010. It was much harder pre 2010 :)